# Use typedef struct in another file in C

Tags: c, struct, c-header

Hello, I'm new to C.

I want to "export" and use a typedef struct in other files but it seems that it doesn't works a lot.

I have those kind of errors

```c
unknown type name 'CAN_frame'
storage size of 'CAN_RxMessage' isn't known
invalid use of undefined type 'struct CAN_frame'
```

Here are my files:

**main.h**

```c
#include "can.h"
typedef struct
{
    uint16_t STDID;  //ID
    uint8_t IDE;
    uint8_t RTR;     //Request frame ou data frame
    uint8_t DLC;     //Nombre d'octets de données utiles
    uint8_t data[8]; //Tableau de 8 octets de données
}CAN_frame;
```

**can.h**

```c
#include "main.h"
```

**can.c**

```c
#include "can.h"
CAN_frame CAN_RxMessage;

void reception_CAN(void)
{
    //CAN_RxMessage filled with data
}
```

Of course I also want to use this CAN_RxMessage filled with data in my main.c (to send it with the usart to my computer).

I tried to use extern, extern struct, struct and manualy defined CAN_frame in my can.c and can.h(but I think it will only overload or redefine CAN_frame in my main.c so it seems useless).

Comment: So `main.h` includes `can.h` and `can.h` includes `main.h`. Recall that inclusion basically dumps file content in place (as text). How is the circular inclusion supposed to work?

Comment: It looks to me like `can.h` includes `main.h`, and `main.h` includes `can.h`.  The pre-processor will probably produce an error about an infinite-loop of include files.

Comment: Learn about how to use header guards to prevent multiple inclusion and inclusion loops.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Comment: **What books did you read about C programming?** I recommend [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/). Then read [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c), the documentation of your C compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), to be used as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) and of your debugger (perhaps [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...). Take inspiration from the source code of existing open source programs (e.g. for [Arduino](http://arduino.cc/)... if you are developing embedded software)

Comment: Even with header guards, it is often problematic to have circular dependencies among headers.  Where such dependencies appear, they can and should be resolved by appropriate refactoring.

Comment: Sorry you are right, I changed that but it still don't work.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I haven't read any books, I'm just trying to lean C for schools projects. I'm using STM32CubeIDE and it obviously deal with STM32 chips.
Thanks for those advices, I will take a look at each books :D

Comment: And your school library don't have books on paper? Or you cannot buy some book at the nearest bookstore? Your comments are in French, I guess you could buy paper journals like [these](https://www.journaux.fr/linux_informatique_1_0_130.html). Near Paris they cost a few € each.

Comment: You could also join [APRIL](https://april.org/) (a non profit association for free software). You can also buy -or borrow- good books in French on C programming (e.g. at http://lmet.fr/ ....), e.g. [*Programmez en langage C*](https://www.academia.edu/29650681/Programmer_en_langage_C_Cours_et_exercices_corrig%C3%A9s_Claude_Delannoy_5%C3%A8_Edition_) by C.Dellanoy

Comment: Thank you, I'm already taking a look at what you sent to me. I figure out what was the error and I planed to go deeper with C, those books you provided will definitely help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is it.

**can.h**

```c
typedef struct _CAN_frame
{
    uint16_t STDID;  //ID
    uint8_t IDE;
    uint8_t RTR;     //Request frame ou data frame
    uint8_t DLC;     //Nombre d'octets de données utiles
    uint8_t data[8]; //Tableau de 8 octets de données
}CAN_frame;
```

**can.c**

```c
#include "can.h"
```

**main.c**

```c
#include "can.h"
CAN_frame CAN_RxMessage;

void reception_CAN(void)
{
    //CAN_RxMessage filled with data
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me! I use also extern to share global variables between files.